# Lambda initialization error with Solaris Studio compiler

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, solaris-studio

Lambda defined in templated class constructor compiles and works on GCC 5.5, but get error on Solaris Studio (former SunPRO) 12.6.

```
        m_method_ptr = [](void* object_ptr, func_ptr_type, ARGS... args) -> R
        {
            return static_cast<unref_type*>(object_ptr)->operator()(args...);
        };
```

with error

```
"fixed_function.hpp", line 52: Error: Cannot use tp::FixedFunction<std::string (), 128>::FixedFunction<main::{lambda at test.cc,21:40}>::{lambda at fixed_function.hpp,52:24} to initialize std::string (*)(void*,std::string (*)()).
"test.cc", line 21:     Where: While instantiating "void tp::FixedFunction<std::string (), 128>::FixedFunction<main::{lambda at test.cc,21:40}>(main::{lambda at test.cc,21:40}&&)".
"test.cc", line 21:     Where: Instantiated from non-template code.
1 Error(s) detected.
```

I have absolutely no idea why. Of course, I've found workaround years ago, but I don't like it and trying to fix that.

Full module code [here](https://github.com/yvoinov/thread-pool-cpp/blob/thread-pool-cpp-round-robin-stealing/include/thread_pool/fixed_function.hpp) (not so big).

I've tried google it, but found nothing useful. When Im commenting out this lambda, error gone. So, it's here.

May be, anybody met such case or can point me right way?

Here is minimal reproducible example. Please, note - it compiles and runs on GCC/CLang, but not on CC (SunStudio).

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <utility>

namespace tp
{

/**
 * @brief The FixedFunction<R(ARGS...), STORAGE_SIZE> class implements
 * functional object.
 * This function is analog of 'std::function' with limited capabilities:
 *  - It supports only move semantics.
 *  - The size of functional objects is limited to storage size.
 * Due to limitations above it is much faster on creation and copying than
 * std::function.
 */
template <typename SIGNATURE, std::size_t STORAGE_SIZE = 128>
class FixedFunction;

template <typename R, typename... ARGS, std::size_t STORAGE_SIZE>
class FixedFunction<R(ARGS...), STORAGE_SIZE>
{

    typedef R (*func_ptr_type)(ARGS...);

public:
    FixedFunction()
        : m_function_ptr(nullptr), m_method_ptr(nullptr),
          m_alloc_ptr(nullptr)
    {
    }

    /**
     * @brief FixedFunction Constructor from functional object.
     * @param object Functor object will be stored in the internal storage
     * using move constructor. Unmovable objects are prohibited explicitly.
     */
    template <typename FUNC>
    FixedFunction(FUNC&& object)
        : FixedFunction()
    {
        typedef typename std::remove_reference<FUNC>::type unref_type;

        static_assert(sizeof(unref_type) < STORAGE_SIZE,
            "functional object doesn't fit into internal storage");
        static_assert(std::is_move_constructible<unref_type>::value,
            "Should be of movable type");

        m_method_ptr = [](void* object_ptr, func_ptr_type, ARGS... args) -> R   // <--- Problem here
        {
            return static_cast<unref_type*>(object_ptr)->operator()(args...);
        };

        m_alloc_ptr = [](void* storage_ptr, void* object_ptr)
        {
            if (object_ptr)
            {
                unref_type* x_object = static_cast<unref_type*>(object_ptr);
                new(storage_ptr) unref_type(std::move(*x_object));
            }
            else
            {
                static_cast<unref_type*>(storage_ptr)->~unref_type();
            }
        };

        m_alloc_ptr(&m_storage, &object);
    }

    /**
     * @brief FixedFunction Constructor from free function or static member.
     */
    template <typename RET, typename... PARAMS>
    FixedFunction(RET (*func_ptr)(PARAMS...))
        : FixedFunction()
    {
        m_function_ptr = func_ptr;
        m_method_ptr = [](void*, func_ptr_type f_ptr, ARGS... args) -> R
        {
            return static_cast<RET (*)(PARAMS...)>(f_ptr)(args...);
        };
    }

    FixedFunction(FixedFunction&& o) : FixedFunction()
    {
        moveFromOther(o);
    }

    FixedFunction& operator=(FixedFunction&& o)
    {
        moveFromOther(o);
        return *this;
    }

    ~FixedFunction()
    {
        if (m_alloc_ptr) m_alloc_ptr(&m_storage, nullptr);
    }

    /**
     * @brief operator () Execute stored functional object.
     * @throws std::runtime_error if no functional object is stored.
     */
    R operator()(ARGS... args)
    {
        if (!m_method_ptr) throw std::runtime_error("call of empty functor");
        return m_method_ptr(&m_storage, m_function_ptr, args...);
    }

private:
    FixedFunction& operator=(const FixedFunction&) = delete;
    FixedFunction(const FixedFunction&) = delete;

    union
    {
        typename std::aligned_storage<STORAGE_SIZE, sizeof(std::size_t)>::type
            m_storage;
        func_ptr_type m_function_ptr;
    };

    typedef R (*method_type)(
        void* object_ptr, func_ptr_type free_func_ptr, ARGS... args);
    method_type m_method_ptr;

    typedef void (*alloc_type)(void* storage_ptr, void* object_ptr);
    alloc_type m_alloc_ptr;

    void moveFromOther(FixedFunction& o)
    {
        if (this == &o) return;

        if (m_alloc_ptr)
        {
            m_alloc_ptr(&m_storage, nullptr);
            m_alloc_ptr = nullptr;
        }
        else
        {
            m_function_ptr = nullptr;
        }

        m_method_ptr = o.m_method_ptr;
        o.m_method_ptr = nullptr;

        if (o.m_alloc_ptr)
        {
            m_alloc_ptr = o.m_alloc_ptr;
            m_alloc_ptr(&m_storage, &o.m_storage);
        }
        else
        {
            m_function_ptr = o.m_function_ptr;
        }
    }
};

}

// 

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    const std::string s1 = "s1";
    tp::FixedFunction<std::string()> f([&s1]() { return s1; });
    auto f1 = std::move(f);
}
```

Will be greatful for any ideas. I see issue somewhere with ARGS instantiation, but can't understand where.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] as code here. What is func_ptr_type? Why do you expect ARGS... to be equivalent to no parameters? If you write a funcion `void f(void*, void(*)(), ...);` that would also not be compatible, so the question title is a bit misleading (the problem in the code is not directly related to lambdas).

Comment: There is no minimal reproducible example, sorry. To reproduce requires all library (by link above) and program source code. As you can see (probably) this is thread pool. Lambda calls via pool post() function. Pool receives free function with void() return with formal parameter. GCC produces runnable binary. CC is not and compilation failed. **func_ptr_type** is defined at the top on module by [link](https://github.com/yvoinov/thread-pool-cpp/blob/thread-pool-cpp-round-robin-stealing/include/thread_pool/fixed_function.hpp): `typedef R (*func_ptr_type)(ARGS...);`

Comment: Of course, I'll try to prepare reproducible example. But I'm afraid for compilation will require Oracle Developer Studio example. As I said, there is no GCC/CLang compilation issue here.

Comment: Guess you right, Werner. Seems problem template related, not lambda(s). However can't see it. I'm not so good in templates.